# Find referenced pipelines in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have many pipelines arranged in folders in my ADF. I want to see if 'Pipeline-A' is being called (referenced) from other pipelines. How to do that?

1. I can run a search in the Json files(repository). Is that my only option?

Answer (score 1):

You can see this in the Pipeline properties inside Data Factory:

[image]